# How does Stack Overflow handle cancelled upvotes from a day that the cap was hit?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit, voting

In this use case:

1. Five days ago, someone hit the daily rep cap (with a great overhead, say 50 upvotes for answers, that would have been like 500 rep). and his first 20 upvotes will be added, the last 30 upvotes will be give up.
2. Today, a voter who vote up his answer 5 days ago canceled his vote. and the vote in the first 20 upvotes, so the wretch lose 10 rep.

What will happen then? Will Stack Overflow recompute the rep of the day, and add 1 upvote from the given up upvotes?

And if the voter changed the upvote to downvote, the lost -12 rep belongs 5 days ago or today?

Comment: Interesting question - I guess the reputation will be lost temporarily, but will be re-added if you recalculate your reputation (because the score is recalculated from scratch then). Don't know for sure though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will be returned when you recalculate your reputation, by going to `/reputation` and clicking the button at the bottom. This will recalculate your reputation based on the current state of all elements, and so capped votes will not be capped until that day is capped under the new calculation.

This will actually help fix a number of issues regarding canceled votes, bounties, and deletions that would reduce the reputation from that day but can be recovered if you got back upvotes that were previously capped.

---

Didn't see that sneaky question at the end. If it was converted to a downvote, this will be reflected *on the day the downvote was cast*. So you'll lose the upvote from 5 days ago, while the downvote will be applied on the current day.

This would also affect if, say, you just retracted the upvote today (thus lose the upvote from 5 days ago), then 2 days later you re-upvote. That new upvote will be placed 2 days later, not from 5 days ago.